# Find multiple longest words and count how many times they repeat

Tags: c#, cpu-word

So i made code that finds longest words in two text files and if that is unique word in first text file it writes to file. But i need to find unique words in first text file and then from those unique words find 10 longest words. Then those 10 words sort from longest to shortest and count how many times it appears in first text file.

```
        string[] LongestWrods(string[] longest1, string[] text2, int longestCount1, out int longestWordText, char[] @char)
    {
        string[] LongestWordsText1 = new string[10];
        longestWordText = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < longestCount1; i++)
        {
            if (RepeatTimes(text2, longest1[i], @char) == 0)
                LongestWordsText1[longestWordText++] = longest1[i];
        }
        return LongestWordsText1;
    }
```

Comment: Is this an assignment, or is it OK to use Linq?

Comment: so you need to  (A) find unique words in the text , (B) get the longest word of those uniques, (C) order those 10 words from longest to shortest? sounds like a  job for [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Also, how are the words stored in the text file? Are there multiple words per line? Or is it one word per line? If multiple words per line, what is the delimiter? Is it a space? Are there even multiple lines in the file?

Comment: That's a lot of requirements, which bit is causing a problem?

Comment: This is an assignment, i guess it is okay to use linq. Text file: there is multiple words per line and there is multiple lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> wordsToCut = File.ReadAllLines("text2.txt").Distinct().ToList();

        List<UniqueWord> uniqueWords = new List<UniqueWord>();

        foreach (string word in File.ReadAllLines("text1.txt"))
        {
            if (wordsToCut.Contains(word) == false)
            {
                UniqueWord uniqueWord = uniqueWords.Where(x => x.Word == word).FirstOrDefault();

                if (uniqueWord != null)
                {
                    uniqueWord.Occurrence++;
                }
                else
                {
                    uniqueWords.Add(new UniqueWord(word));
                }
            }
        }

        uniqueWords = uniqueWords.OrderByDescending(x => x.Word.Length).Take(10).ToList();
    }
}

public class UniqueWord
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int Occurrence { get; set; }

    public UniqueWord(string word)
    {
        Word = word;
        Occurrence = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that i have two text files. So i need find those words which appears in only text1 and not in text2

Comment: Edited, now it should be ok

Comment: One more thing... How to use  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries and remove all: ' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t' on both file reads?

Answer (score 0):

Of course not the best option, but fastest one i could get. `largestWordsCount` contains all the 10 largest unique words and how times it appears in text for each.

```
var text = "The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, standard used standard since the 1500s \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed";
var splittedText = text.Split(' ');
var uniqueWords = new HashSet<string>(splittedText);
var tenLargestWords = uniqueWords.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).Take(10);
var largestWordsCount = tenLargestWords.Select(word => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(word, Regex.Matches(text, word).Count)).ToList();
```